# Mutual inductance theoretically decreasing while EMF is increasing in 2 square coil system

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, inductance

I have a quick question regarding electricity and magnetism. I am measuring the induced emf in a square coil of wire with an inductance of 439uH (the other coil is also 439uH and is the same shape). I am powering coil 1 with a 125kHz 5V 50mA current. when i put the coils next to each other (8.1 mm apart), the induced emf is about 10V. when i move them further apart to about 3 centimers, then the induced emf increases to about 30V. After that, the emf begins to decrease once again if I make z increase. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening? I feel like the emf should have kept descreasing from the beginnning.

The equation I am using for the B field of coil 1 is $B = \frac{N4w^2\mu_0I}{\pi\sqrt{2w^2+4z^2}(w^2+4z^2)}$, where $w$ is the width of the square loop, $z$ is the distance between the two square loops, and $N$ is the number of coils. When $z$ is smallest, $B$ is greatest (meaning that the mutual inductance is greater). However, $B$ decreases as $z$ increases, so I am not entirely sure why I am seeing the effect described above.

(Source for equation: http://physicspages.com/2013/04/11/magnetic-field-of-square-current-loop/)

Comment: Given the parameters I would guess that your coils are near self-resonance. As long as they are closely coupled, there is strong damping, but when you pull them apart, the quality factor of the secondary coil increases greatly. So while your coupling is smaller, the increased Q leads to a higher resonant voltage. Congrats... you may just have discovered the working principle of a Tesla coil!